# Why is CakePHP duplicating my queries? (this is not the same "too many queries" problem that is usually asked)

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3, has-and-belongs-to-many, has-many

I've defined these relationships in my models:

Lead hasMany Job
Job HABTM Employee
Job HABTM Truck

I'm trying to do a `find('all')` from my Truck model, and limit the results to:

1. All Trucks,
2. all jobs associated with those trucks that have a certain pickup date,
3. the employees assigned to those jobs,
4. and the lead associated with the job.

Here is my find operation:

```
// app/models/truck.php
$this->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Job' => array(
            'Employee',
            'Lead',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Job.pickup_date' => $date
            )
        )
    )
));
```

For some reason, Cake does the query to find Employees TWICE.  This leads to having all employees represented two times for each job.  Here is the SQL dump:

1. ```
   SELECT `Truck`.`id`, `Truck`.`truck_number`
   FROM   `trucks` AS `Truck`
   WHERE  1 = 1;
   ```
2. ```
   SELECT `Job`.`id`, `Job`.`lead_id`, `Job`.`city`,
          `JobsTruck`.`id`, `JobsTruck`.`job_id`, `JobsTruck`.`truck_id`
   FROM   `jobs` AS `Job`
   JOIN   `jobs_trucks` AS `JobsTruck` ON (`JobsTruck`.`truck_id` IN (2, 3)
   AND    `JobsTruck`.`job_id` = `Job`.`id`)
   WHERE  `Job`.`pickup_date` = '2010-10-06'
   ```
3. ```
   SELECT `Lead`.`id`, `Lead`.`name`, `Lead`.`created` FROM `leads` AS `Lead`
   WHERE  `Lead`.`id` = 4
   ```
4. ```
   SELECT `Employee`.`id`, `Employee`.`name`, `Employee`.`created`,
          `EmployeesJob`.`id`, `EmployeesJob`.`employee_id`,
          `EmployeesJob`.`job_id`
   FROM   `employees` AS `Employee`
   JOIN   `employees_jobs` AS `EmployeesJob`
          ON (
              `EmployeesJob`.`job_id` = 1 AND
              `EmployeesJob`.`employee_id` = `Employee`.`id`
          )
   ```
5. ```
   SELECT `Lead`.`id`, `Lead`.`name`, `Lead`.`created` FROM `leads` AS `Lead`
   WHERE  `Lead`.`id` = 4
   ```
6. ```
   SELECT `Employee`.`id`, `Employee`.`name`, `Employee`.`created`,
          `EmployeesJob`.`id`, `EmployeesJob`.`employee_id`,
          `EmployeesJob`.`job_id`
   FROM   `employees` AS `Employee`
   JOIN   `employees_jobs` AS `EmployeesJob`
          ON (
              `EmployeesJob`.`job_id` = 1 AND
              `EmployeesJob`.`employee_id` = `Employee`.`id`
          )
   ```

Notice that the last two queries are duplicates.  Did I do something wrong that I'm missing?

**UPDATE**
It seems Cake sends a duplicate query for every truck.  Now that I have 15 records in the trucks table, the queries to `leads` and `employees` are duplicated 15 times each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why there are two queries duplicated but maybe this behavior can help:

https://github.com/Terr/linkable

**UPDATE**

This kind of problem is well known:

- [Duplicate Queries in
  MODEL->HABTM->HABTM->HasMany
  relationship](http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/21c35f7893fb4b3c/c147bbfe0879881e?lnk=gst&q=duplicate#c147bbfe0879881e)
- [Duplicate Queries Problem with
  Containable](http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/f0f17b4f7151139f/48383fff80bc75cd?lnk=gst&q=duplicate#48383fff80bc75cd)
- [Ticket](https://trac.cakephp.org/ticket/5336)

Comment: This looks intriguing.  I'll check it out when I get to work on Monday.

Comment: Awesome, Rio.  Thanks for the fact finding.

Comment: So that Ticket is 2 years old.  Apparently they are targeting CakePHP 2.0 to fix the issue.  For now I'm resorting to splitting up the queries into multiple calls to `$this->find` and building the data array manually, which sucks, but it sucks a lot less when you go from 80 queries to 4 queries.

Comment: Yes, apparently in cakephp 2.0 the problem will be fixed. In the meantime, probably I would split the queries, as you're doing, or I would change the associations (http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data#footer)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to join the found `Job/s` to a specific `Truck`.

*(I hope my explanation isn't too hard to understand, but CakePHP can be that way sometimes! imho)*

The `Jobs` are being attributed to the `Trucks` in an almost arbitrary way (my memory of Cake is that this can happen); the nature of the HABTM call attaches the `Job/s` to each of the 15 `Trucks`. This seems to be the current process from my point of view;

- Get all trucks.
- Get all jobs for those trucks where the date is *x*.
- [Problem 1] Attach the found `Jobs` to each `Truck` (that is your 15 trucks), but attached to every `Truck`.
- [Problem 2] Get all Leads/Employees related to that Job, *again* for each `Truck`.

Problem 1: The source of the issue. You can see in the second query (SELECT `Job`...), where it uses the correct `truck_id`'s in the ON statement, but Cake cannot "join" these `Jobs` back into the right `Truck`, because it is a different query! So it joins the found jobs to each `Truck`.

Problem 2: This is the 'real' problem, for Cake does not construct long JOIN statements, so there is no way to find the `Employees`/`Leads` only for those `Trucks` that you want. That is why it finds them for each Truck, this is because you are doing a `FindAll` on `Truck`.

I hope that makes sense. You need to do a find all on `Jobs`, since that is the *'center'* of the query (pickup_date).

```
$this->loadModel('Job');
$whatev = $this->Job->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Job' => array(
            'Truck',
            'Employee',
            'Lead',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Job.pickup_date' => $date
            )
        )
    )
));
```

CakePHP queries really only work when you find one/all of a certain model, it is better to start in the middle and work either side if you have a double HABTM relationship. If you wish to 'sort' by Truck, then you might have to write you're own query (model method) to accomplish the task yourself. In raw SQL this query may be easy, in abstracted PHP super-cake-ness this is difficult for CakePHP to allow.

Happy baking, as they say!

Comment: This looks promising, but did you mean to contain Job on Job?

Comment: I have a secret.  There's another relationship: `Truck -> hasMany -> TruckLog`.  (I left it out of the example for simplicity's sake) When moving the query to centralize around `Job` instead of `Truck`, I start getting the same problem with `TruckLog` (the queries are duplicated for every job associated with a truck).

Comment: You are right about the Job containing Job, that was an oversight of mine. Particularly with the extra HABTM relationship TruckLog, you will almost certainly need to create a model method that finds exactly what you want. You may either need to SQL query of your own using $Model->query(), and probably use a sub-query/s to achieve this in one query (faster for performance probably). Or you might have a model method that finds these individually, and use array merge (http://book.cakephp.org/view/679/merge) to process the results for each item.

Answer (score -3):

You want LEFT JOIN instead of JOIN.

Don't ask me how to do it in cakephp, i'm happy my code currently works. ^^

Comment: The question is about CakePHP.  Good day sir.

Comment: ::sigh:: The result set is *fine*.  Changing the JOIN will not fix the problem.  The problem is that CakePHP is firing off the same queries multiple times.  thaRRR11! to you.